# Form loads incorrectly second time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a form that when the browser opens it the first time it loads properly. The second time a browser loads it however it does so improperly and I'm banging my head trying to figure out why.. Any help is very appreciated.

**Correct Loading:**

```
<div class="radiobox">
    <label>
        <input id="rbShipMethod_FxStandard" type="radio" name="shipmethod" value="rbShipMethod_FxStandard" checked="checked">
    <span>FedEx - Standard / Ground : $10.97</span>
</label>
```

**Incorrect Loading:**

```
<div class="radiobox">
    <label>
        <span disabled="disabled">
            <input id="rbShipMethod_FxStandard" type="radio" name="shipmethod" value="rbShipMethod_FxStandard" disabled="disabled">
        </span>
        <span>FedEx - Standard / Ground : $10.97</span>
</label>
```

**associated code from the aspx file**

```
<div class="radiobox">
    <label>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbShipMethod_FxStandard" runat="server" GroupName="shipmethod"></asp:RadioButton>
        <span>FedEx - Standard / Ground : $<asp:Literal ID="ltShipCharge_FxStandard" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

**Edit: Adding Request Page_Load Method**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.hdShippingAddressAdd.Value = "";
        if (this.GetLoginCustomerID() <= 0 & Strings.Len(this.GetCurrentCartID()) <= 0)
        {
            this.Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
        }
        this.BindYear();
        this.BindOrderDetail();
        this.BindAddress();
    }
}
```

This was requested, going to do more reading. I should have stated I'm very new to this (PHP dev who also happens to be the resident fix-it guy) so I'm not 100% sure what I'm looking for. 
Also this was an inherited project, without the source. I used Telerik to decompile the dll and when I try to build this in VS it has 130 or so errors.. So if there's a way around this without editing the source I'd be stoked. I'm looking at both this function and the build errors now

Comment: Is there any relevant code in your code behind file that might be affecting your radio button?

Comment: Per @ScoobyDrew18, given that the second time it loads the checkbox is disabled, the first place I'd look is your Page_Load method.  Maybe you've got some logic in there for postbacks?

Comment: I've added the requested method along with a bit more information. I'm gonna do more research, but any direction is greatly appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: tagging users @Tim